# What to do about the deprecated Qt3DRender::QBuffer::BufferType?

Tags: qt, qt3d

Is there any substitute? Or should we just ignore them and don't specify the type anymore? Also, I wonder what is the reason behind deprecating them in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I am working on Qt.5.14 and I am just ignoring it and don't set the type in the first place anymore. This seems to be inline with the documentation as well: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qbuffer-obsolete.html

Most likely this doesn't match OpenGL usage anymore. what buffer data is used for is specified in an attribute that references the data in a buffer.